# Join historical data with cross-sectional data

Tags: powerbi

Let's say I have cross-sectional data about clients and products that goes like this:

```
DATASET 1
CLIENT_ID  PRODUCT
1          foo
1          bar
2          foo
3          foo   
3          bar
3          baz
```

So I have potentially many products for every client.

Now let's say I have a new dataset containing historical data about one specific variable, and for every client. The data would be like this:

```
DATASET 2
CLIENT_ID  DATE  VARIABLE
1          2010  2.1
1          2011  2.8
1          2012  3.6
1          2013  3.4
1          2014  3.2
1          2015  3.9
2          2010  2.4
2          2011  2.6
2          2012  3.2
etc.
```

This two datasets are apart and once in Power BI, I have a hard time joining them into a dashboard that works proprely. I want the dashboard to show information from dataset 1 (cross-sectional data), but I'd like to filter my dataset 2 (historical data) based on the selected client in dataset 1.

In other words, you select a client and get the information from dataset 1, but you are also shown the historical data for this particular client. Any ideas?

EDIT

I want to filter the second dataset based on what's selected in the first one. For example, I would have a drop-down menu to filter all the info about a client in dataset 1, but also in dataset 2.

Let's say I have selected Client 1, I'd like to be able to use in my dashboard:

```
DATASET 1                           DATASET 2
CLIENT_ID  PRODUCT  EMAIL  CITY     CLIENT_ID  DATE  VARIABLE
1          foo      abc    NY       1          2010  2.1
1          bar      def    LA       1          2011  2.3
1          baz      ghi    NY       1          2012  2.8
etc.
```

Comment: Please edit question to include the relevant data-model and outcome you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create an intermediary dataset with only the CLIENT_IDs, with all duplicates dropped. That way, I was able to create a one-to-many relationship with my two other datasets, and then using a slice in Power BI to filter all my data based on that intermediary dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can likely declare a relationship (in the model tab) between the CLIENT_ID in dataset 1 and the CLIENT_ID in dataset_2. Based on your description it would probably be a many to many relationship. Once you do this if you create a filter (such as a slicer) on the client then it should filter out by client in both datasets.

Comment: I tried that, but the problem was that with a many-to-many relationship, Power BI acted as if every line in my second dataset was there more than once.